# Inverse of Homomorphism

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, normal-subgroups, inverse-function, group-homomorphism

I am a little confused when working with the inverse of a homomorphism, this specifically came up when proving the following claim:

Let $\phi$ be some homomorphism from $G_1\rightarrow G_2$:
$$H_2 \subset G_2\textrm{ is a normal subgroup } \Rightarrow \phi^{-1}(H_2)\subset G_1 \textrm{ is a normal subgroup}$$

The proof for this begins by stating that
$$e_1\in\phi^{-1}(H_2)\textrm{ since } \phi(e_1)=e_2\in H_2$$
But since $\phi$ is a homorphism, it is not nessesarily surjective or injective. So there could be many terms in $g_1,g_2,...\in G_1$ such that $\phi(g_1)=\phi(g_2)=...=e_1$. So does $\phi^{-1}(e_1)$ return all of these values? Can the inverse function of a Homomorphism return multiple values per input? In general, when dealing with inverse functions, should I think of the inverse as a function that will return every coresponding value?

Comment: Inverse image, not inverse function.

Comment: So an inverse function can only exist if the function is a bijection, but the inverse image exist for any mapping?

Comment: Yes, precisely.

Comment: That's why for a homomorphism $\phi$,  "$\phi^{-1}(H)$" is misleading. I prefer $\phi^{\leftarrow}(H)$.

Comment: Besides this clarification, do you feel confident with the claim?

Comment: Now I do yes, Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

The expression $\phi^{-1}(H_2)$ means the set $\{g\in H_1\mid\phi(g)\in H_2\}$, for *any* function $\phi$, even if it has no inverse.